# Using the same decorator (with arguments) with functions and methods

Tags: python, function, methods, arguments, decorator

I have been trying to create a decorator that can be used with both functions and methods in python.  This on it's own is not that hard, but when creating a decorator that takes arguments, it seems to be.

```
class methods(object):
    def __init__(self, *_methods):
        self.methods = _methods

    def __call__(self, func): 
        def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
            print request
            return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return inner

    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        new_func = self.func.__get__(obj, type)
        return self.__class__(new_func)
```

The above code wraps the function/method correctly, but in the case of a method, the `request` argument is the instance it is operating on, not the first non-self argument.

Is there a way to tell if the decorator is being applied to a function instead of a method, and deal accordingly?

Comment: Of course, the best solution now is to use `wrapt`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To expand on the `__get__` approach. This can be generalized into a decorator decorator.

```
class _MethodDecoratorAdaptor(object):
    def __init__(self, decorator, func):
        self.decorator = decorator
        self.func = func
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.decorator(self.func)(*args, **kwargs)
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.decorator(self.func.__get__(instance, owner))

def auto_adapt_to_methods(decorator):
    """Allows you to use the same decorator on methods and functions,
    hiding the self argument from the decorator."""
    def adapt(func):
        return _MethodDecoratorAdaptor(decorator, func)
    return adapt
```

In this way you can just make your decorator automatically adapt to the conditions it is used in.

```
def allowed(*allowed_methods):
    @auto_adapt_to_methods
    def wrapper(func):
        def wrapped(request):
            if request not in allowed_methods:
                raise ValueError("Invalid method %s" % request)
            return func(request)
        return wrapped
    return wrapper
```

Notice that the wrapper function is called on all function calls, so don't do anything expensive there.

Usage of the decorator:

```
class Foo(object):
    @allowed('GET', 'POST')
    def do(self, request):
        print "Request %s on %s" % (request, self)

@allowed('GET')
def do(request):
    print "Plain request %s" % request

Foo().do('GET')  # Works
Foo().do('POST') # Raises
```

Comment: You should add `update_wrapper(self, func)` to the *beginning* of `_MethodDecoratorAdaptor.__init__` (where update_wrapper is from functools module). This makes the resulting decorators preserve custom attributes on the functions/callables they decorate, while keeping them composable as well.

Comment: I've discovered that this method only works in some circumstances, and is extremely difficult to debug when it doesn't work. http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/msg/f36976f5cfbcbeb3

Comment: @spookylukey Actually the way this is handled in Django is quite clean too.

Comment: @Juanlu001 How does Django handle this?

Comment: @Satoru.Logic the email linked above and the source code explain it.

Comment: What does `self.decorator(self.func.__get__(instance, owner))` do? Somebody here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3296318/3578468) suggested `partial(self.__call__, obj)` instead. The partial version makes 100% sense to me. I do not understand what your version does. Both seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

The decorator is always applied to a function object -- have the decorator `print` the type of its argument and you'll be able to confirm that; and it should generally return a function object, too (which is already a decorator with the proper `__get__`!-) although there are exceptions to the latter.

I.e, in the code:

```
class X(object):

  @deco
  def f(self): pass
```

`deco(f)` is called within the class body, and, while you're still there, `f` is a function, not an instance of a method type. (The method is manufactured and returned in `f`'s `__get__` when later `f` is accessed as an attribute of `X` or an instance thereof).

Maybe you can better explain one toy use you'd want for your decorator, so we can be of more help...?

**Edit**: this goes for decorators with arguments, too, i.e.

```
class X(object):

  @deco(23)
  def f(self): pass
```

then it's `deco(23)(f)` that's called in the class body, `f` is still a function object when passed as the argument to whatever callable `deco(23)` returns, and that callable should still return a function object (generally -- with exceptions;-).

Answer (score 5):

Since you're already defining a `__get__` to use your decorator on the Bound Method, you could pass a flag telling it if it's being used on a method or function.

```
class methods(object):
    def __init__(self, *_methods, called_on_method=False):
        self.methods = _methods
        self.called_on_method

    def __call__(self, func):
        if self.called_on_method:
            def inner(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                print request
                return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
                print request
                return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return inner

    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        new_func = self.func.__get__(obj, type)
        return self.__class__(new_func, called_on_method=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a general way I found to detect whether a decorated callable is a function or method:

```
import functools

class decorator(object):

  def __init__(self, func):
    self._func = func
    self._obj = None
    self._wrapped = None

  def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self._wrapped:
      if self._obj:
        self._wrapped = self._wrap_method(self._func)
        self._wrapped = functools.partial(self._wrapped, self._obj)
      else:
        self._wrapped = self._wrap_function(self._func)
    return self._wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

  def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
    self._obj = obj
    return self

  def _wrap_method(self, method):
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
      print('Method called on {}:'.format(type(self).__name__))
      return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return inner

  def _wrap_function(self, function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
      print('Function called:')
      return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner
```

Example usage:

```
class Foo(object):
  @decorator
  def foo(self, foo, bar):
    print(foo, bar)

@decorator
def foo(foo, bar):
  print(foo, bar)

foo(12, bar=42)      # Function called: 12 42
foo(12, 42)          # Function called: 12 42
obj = Foo()
obj.foo(12, bar=42)  # Method called on Foo: 12 42
obj.foo(12, 42)      # Method called on Foo: 12 42
```

Answer (score 2):

A partial (specific) solution I have come up with relies on exception handling.  I am attempting to create a decorator to only allow certain HttpRequest methods, but make it work with both functions that are views, and methods that are views.

So, this class will do what I want:

```
class methods(object):
    def __init__(self, *_methods):
        self.methods = _methods

    def __call__(self, func): 
        @wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                if args[0].method in self.methods:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except AttributeError:
                if args[1].method in self.methods:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
            return HttpResponseMethodNotAllowed(self.methods)
        return inner
```

Here are the two use cases: decorating a function:

```
@methods("GET")
def view_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

and decorating methods of a class:

```
class ViewContainer(object):
    # ...

    @methods("GET", "PUT")
    def object(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        # stuff that needs a reference to self...
        pass
```

Is there a better solution than to use exception handling?