# Decorating class methods - how to pass the instance to the decorator?

Tags: python, python-decorators

This is Python 2.5, and it's [GAE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/) too, not that it matters.

I have the following code. I'm decorating the foo() method in bar, using the `dec_check` class as a decorator.

```
class dec_check(object):

  def __init__(self, f):
    self.func = f

  def __call__(self):
    print 'In dec_check.__init__()'
    self.func()

class bar(object):

  @dec_check
  def foo(self):
    print 'In bar.foo()'

b = bar()
b.foo()
```

When executing this I was hoping to see:

```
In dec_check.__init__()
In bar.foo()
```

But I'm getting `TypeError: foo() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)` as `.foo()`, being an object method, takes `self` as an argument. I'm guessing problem is that the instance of `bar` doesn't actually exist when I'm executing the decorator code.

**So how do I pass an instance of `bar` to the decorator class?**

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You need to make the decorator into a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) -- either by ensuring its (meta)class has a `__get__` method, or, **way** simpler, by using a decorator *function* instead of a decorator *class* (since functions are already descriptors).  E.g.:

```
def dec_check(f):
  def deco(self):
    print 'In deco'
    f(self)
  return deco

class bar(object):
  @dec_check
  def foo(self):
    print 'in bar.foo'

b = bar()
b.foo()
```

this prints

```
In deco
in bar.foo
```

as desired.

Comment: Change the `f(self)` line to `return f(self)` to pass the return of `foo` back to the caller.

Comment: Broken link to the descriptor page.

Comment: @Apteryx: I linked [the Python docs on descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors); dry, but covers them well enough.

Comment: How would one pass some args to the decorator with this implementation?

Comment: @mhyousefi please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654. We have more or less a textbook about decorators on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 64):

Alex's answer suffices when a function is sufficient. However, when you need a class you can make it work by adding the following method to the decorator class.

```
def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
    """Support instance methods."""
    import functools
    return functools.partial(self.__call__, obj)
```

To understand this you need to understand the descriptor protocol. The descriptor protocol is the mechanism for binding a thing to an instance. It consists of `__get__`, `__set__` and `__delete__`, which are called when the thing is got, set or deleted from the instances dictionary.

In this case when the thing is got from the instance we are binding the first argument of its `__call__` method to the instance, using partial. This is done automatically for member functions when the class is constructed, but for a synthetic member function like this we need to do it explicitly.

Comment: @Gilbert The descriptor protocol is the mechanism for binding a thing to an instance. It consists of __ get __, __ set __ and __ delete __, which are called when the thing is got, set or deleted from the instances dictionary. In this case when the thing is got from the instance we are binding the first argument of it's __ call __ method to the instance, using partial. This is done automatically for member functions when the class is constructed, but for a synthetic member function like this we need to do it explicitly.

Comment: So what about if the decorator takes arguments?

Comment: python docs have a [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) section

Comment: More detailed explanation with code:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469956/python-decorator-self-is-mixed-up

Comment: A better way to implement `__get__` is to use `types.MethodType` to make an actual bound (or in some cases on Py2, unbound) method object. On Py2, you'd make the `__get__` body `return types.MethodType(self, instance, instancetype)`; on Py3, you'd first test for `None` on `instance` to avoid binding (`if instance is None: return self`), and otherwise, you'd `return types.MethodType(self, instance)`. Full example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57808792/364696). Put the `import` outside the `__get__` though; `import` (even cached) is relatively expensive for simple attribute lookup.

Comment: I think your answer should be the one validated because it is more in relation with the context (Using a decorator as a class). Thanks sir!

Answer (score 12):

If you want to write the decorator as a class you can do:

```
from functools import update_wrapper, partial

class MyDecorator(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        update_wrapper(self, func)
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        """Support instance methods."""
        return partial(self.__call__, obj)

    def __call__(self, obj, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Logic here')
        return self.func(obj, *args, **kwargs)

my_decorator = MyDecorator

class MyClass(object):
     @my_decorator
     def my_method(self):
         pass
```

Comment: How would one pass arguments to this decorator? I tried adding as extra argument to the `__init__` method, but then I don't really know what to pass in for `func` when instantiating the decorator: `@my_decorator(func, given_arg)`.

Comment: @mhyousefi Were you able to find the answer to this?

Comment: @Ferus honestly I don't remember. :) Will update this if I do.

Comment: @mhyousefi No problem I actually came up with a solution by adding in the constructor `self.func = decorator()(self.func)` instead of adding a decorator.

Comment: this one should be the best answer!!!

Comment: Arguments are in `args` and `kwargs` in `__call__` method