# Python decorator, self is mixed up

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am new to Python decorators (wow, great feature!), and I have trouble getting the following to work because the `self` argument gets sort of mixed up.

```
#this is the decorator
class cacher(object):

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
        self.cache = {}

    def __call__(self, *args):
        fname = self.f.__name__
        if (fname not in self.cache):
            self.cache[fname] = self.f(self,*args)
        else:
            print "using cache"
        return self.cache[fname]

class Session(p.Session):

    def __init__(self, user, passw):
        self.pl = p.Session(user, passw)

    @cacher
    def get_something(self):
        print "get_something called with self = %s "% self
        return self.pl.get_something()

s = Session(u,p)
s.get_something()
```

When I run this, I get:

```
get_something called with self = <__main__.cacher object at 0x020870F0> 
Traceback:
...
AttributeError: 'cacher' object has no attribute 'pl'
```

for the line where I do `self.cache[fname] = self.f(self,*args)`

**The problem** - Obviously, the problem is that `self` is the cacher object instead of a Session instance, which indeed doesn't have a `pl` attribute. However I can't find how to solve this.

**Solutions I've considered, but can't use** - I thought of making the decorator class return a function instead of a value (like in section 2.1 of this [article](http://www.siafoo.net/article/68#the-wrapper-function)) so that `self` is evaluated in the right context, but that isn't possible since my decorator is implemented as a class and uses the build-in  `__call__` method. Then I thought to *not* use a class for my decorator, so that I don't need the __call__method, but I can't do that because I need to keep state between decorator calls (i.e. for keeping track of what is in the `self.cache` attribute).

**Question** - So, apart from using a global `cache` dictionary variable (which I didn't try, but assume will work), is there any other way to make this decorator work?

Edit: this SO question seems similar [Decorating python class methods, how do I pass the instance to the decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365701/decorating-python-class-methods-how-do-i-pass-the-instance-to-the-decorator)

Comment: You are aware that this way, all instances of `Session` will share the same cache?

Comment: yes, I've not yet completed the code but I roughly thought of given an extra session argument somewhere to keep separate caches .

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use the [descriptor protocol](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) like this:

```
import functools

class cacher(object):

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
        self.cache = {}

    def __call__(self, *args):
        fname = self.f.__name__
        if (fname not in self.cache):
            self.cache[fname] = self.f(self,*args)
        else:
            print "using cache"
        return self.cache[fname]

    def __get__(self, instance, instancetype):
        """Implement the descriptor protocol to make decorating instance 
        method possible.

        """

        # Return a partial function with the first argument is the instance 
        #   of the class decorated.
        return functools.partial(self.__call__, instance)
```

**Edit :**

**How it's work ?**

Using the descriptor protocol in the decorator will allow us to access the method decorated with the correct instance as self, maybe some code can help better:

Now when we will do:

```
class Session(p.Session):
    ...

    @cacher
    def get_something(self):
        print "get_something called with self = %s "% self
        return self.pl.get_something()
```

equivalent to:

```
class Session(p.Session):
    ...

    def get_something(self):
        print "get_something called with self = %s "% self
        return self.pl.get_something()

    get_something = cacher(get_something)
```

So now get_something is an instance of cacher . so when we will call the method get_something it will be translated to this (because of the descriptor protocol):

```
session = Session()
session.get_something  
#  <==> 
session.get_something.__get__(get_something, session, <type ..>)
# N.B: get_something is an instance of cacher class.
```

and because :

```
session.get_something.__get__(get_something, session, <type ..>)
# return
get_something.__call__(session, ...) # the partial function.
```

so

```
session.get_something(*args)
# <==>
get_something.__call__(session, *args)
```

Hopefully this will explain how it work :)

Comment: This indeed does it, although I still have to wrap my brain around the description in the link you provided to understand what is exactly going on. I guess that `self` (in `f(self, *args)`) is resolved through the automatic `__get__` call. But doesn't that provide wrong resolution for `self` in all other cases, e.g. `self.cache[fname]` and even `self.f`?

Comment: @Rabarberski: i just edited my answer to include an explanation , hopefully it will be useful :)

Comment: A better way to implement `__get__` is to use `types.MethodType` to make an actual bound (or in some cases on Py2, unbound) method object. On Py2, you'd make the `__get__` body `return types.MethodType(self, instance, instancetype)`; on Py3, you'd first test for `None` on `instance` to avoid binding (`if instance is None: return self`), and otherwise, you'd `return types.MethodType(self, instance)`. Full example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57808792/364696).

Answer (score 4):

Closures are often a better way to go, since you don't have to muck about with the descriptor protocol. Saving mutable state across calls is even easier than with a class, since you just stick the mutable object in the containing scope (references to immutable objects can be handled either via the `nonlocal` keyword, or by stashing them in a mutable object like a single-entry list).

```
#this is the decorator
from functools import wraps
def cacher(f):
    # No point using a dict, since we only ever cache one value
    # If you meant to create cache entries for different arguments
    # check the memoise decorator linked in other answers
    print("cacher called")
    cache = []
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwds):
        print ("wrapped called")
        if not cache:
            print("calculating and caching result")
            cache.append(f(*args, **kwds))
        return cache[0]
    return wrapped

class C:
    @cacher
    def get_something(self):
        print "get_something called with self = %s "% self

C().get_something()
C().get_something()
```

If you aren't completely familiar with the way closures work, adding more print statements (as I have above) can be illustrative. You will see that `cacher` is only called as the function is defined, but `wrapped` is called each time the method is called.

This does highlight how you need to be careful with memoisation techniques and instance methods though - if you aren't careful to account for changes in the value of `self`, you will end up sharing cached answers across instances, which may not be what you want.

Comment: Hmm, I don't get it. The cache variable content will not be preserved between calls, no? I've looked up `wraps`, but I think I suffer from information overload, with the meaning and usefulness of `partial()` (from a previous answer) slowly trickling through. Finally, the dict is necessary because you want a different cache (key) for each function you apply `cacher` to, no?

Comment: No, because cache is created when `cacher` is called, which only happens at function definition time. `wrapped` is created at the same time, and every call of `wrapped` will see that same original `cache` definition. `wraps()` is just a helper to copy `__name__`, `__doc__` and other details from `f` to `wrapped` so the decorated function looks more like the original.

Comment: This explanation as to how decorators work in general may also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481739/how-does-this-python-decorator-work

Answer (score 1):

First, you explicitly pass `cacher` object as first argument in the following line:

```
self.cache[fname] = self.f(self,*args)
```

Python automatically adds `self` to the list of arguments for methods only. It converts functions (but not other callables as your `cacher` object!) defined in class namespace to methods. To get such behavior I see two ways:

1. Change your decorator to return function by using closures.
2. Implement descriptor protocol to pass `self` argument yourself as it's done in [memoize decorator recipe](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize).

Comment: I think solution (1) is not an option for the arguments I've given in my post. Or I am wrong about this? Solution (2) seems identical to singularity's answer. Thanks for the memoize link!

Comment: The only argument I see is keeping state between calls. Sure, it's possible via mutable argument[s] to decorator function.