# How does this python decorator work?

Tags: python, decorator

**Edit/Clarification to make my question specific to my query**: 
*I can see how the decorator static log function is called  but I don't see how *_* is called and how the result of it is the result of log. I cam see how the entry/enter stuff works*

```
class logger:
    @staticmethod
    def log(func):
        def ___(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                print "Entering: [%s] with parameters %s" % (func.__name__, args)
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception, e:
                    print 'Exception in %s : %s' % (func.__name__, e)
            finally:
                print "Exiting: [%s]" % func.__name__
        return ___


class x:
      @logger.log
      def first_x_method(self):
          print 'doing first_x_method stuff...'

x().first_x_method()
```

gives this output:

```
Entering: [first_x_method] with parameters (<__main__.x instance at 0x0000000001F45648>,)
doing first_x_method stuff...
Exiting: [first_x_method]
```

I can see that logger is a class with a static method that is used to decorate  (`@logger.log`) first_x_method.

However I don't understand why the `___` sub method (and it can be any name) is called.

Comment: In case it's not obvious: don't name functions "___" ...

Comment: no that was just for effect. I actually have it called wrap

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fundamental fact about decorators is that

```
@decorator
def func(): ...
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
def func(): ...
func=decorator(func)
```

So,

```
@logger.log
def first_x_method(self): ...
```

is the same as

```
def first_x_method(self): ...
first_x_method=logger.log(first_x_method)
```

and so the `logger.log` static method is called with argument `func = first_x_method`.

Inside the call to `logger.log(first_x_method)`, the sub method `__` is defined and returned.

`first_x_method=logger.log(first_x_method)` thus sets `first_x_method` to refer to the sub method `__`.

The parenthesis in `first_x_method()` tells Python to call the method `first_x_method`.

So `x().first_x_method()` first instantiates an instance of the class x, and then calls the method `first_x_method` (with x() supplied as the first argument).

Since `first_x_method` refers to `__`, it is `__` that gets called.

Comment: please see changed question. Thanks for the great example it explains the mechanics of the function replacement nicely but that was the bit I understood.

Comment: I don't think you do, actually... In your question you note that you don't understand how `___` is called, which is _exactly_ what is answered here (and again in @yan's answer). In a nutshell, `first_x_method` _is_ `___`.

Comment: @Artanis: Thankyou I'm sure you've explained but I cannot see how the sub function ___ inside log is called? "Inside the call to logger.log(first_x_method), the sub method __ is defined and returned" this is the bit I don't understand. I appreciate that it is but I cannot see the logic that says just defining the function indicates that it's called. I a python n0ob so this may be SOP.

Comment: Forget that. Thank you I had misread the indentation on return ___. I mistook this to mean return from the wrapped function. I can now see that how log is returning the wrapper!.

Answer (score 2):

A decorator is a function that accepts a function as an argument and returns a "decorated" function that will actually be used when it's called.

In this case `logger.log` is passed the function `first_x_method`. The actual decorator implementation creates a function that prints a message before and after running its argument, and returns that function (in this case, called `___`). So in effect, every time you call `first_x_method`, you're actually calling `____`, which maintains a reference to `first_x_method` as `func`.

In other words, `____` "captures" `first_x_method` and replaces it. Whenever it's called, it will first print something, call the function it has a reference to, and then print something again.

edit: Maybe this simplified example can help you understand it:

```
def decorate(func):
  print "Decorate called"
  def internal(*args, **kwargs):
    print "Calling internal"
    func(*args, **kwargs)
    print "Original function returned: "
  print "Created the decorated function, returning."
  return internal

@decorate
def foo(s):
  print "foo called with: ", s
  return 42

foo('hello')
```

Comment: thank you. What I'm trying to understand is how the call to log results in ___ being called.

Comment: log gets called as a decorator (which it in turn defines `___`, but doesn't call it) when the function being decorated is *defined*. When the actual function that was decorated gets called, that's when `___` get's triggered, since the decorator replaced the original function with `___`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def decorate(fn):
    def wrapper():
        fn()
    print 'Wrapping function ', wrapper
    return wrapper

def x():
    pass

print 'Original x ', x

x = decorate(x)

print 'New x ', x
```

Output:

```
Original x <function x at 0x7f3c51e9a758>
Wrapping function <function wrapper at 0x7f3c51e9a7d0>
New x  <function wrapper at 0x7f3c51e9a7d0>
```

Note how `x` is now the same as `wrapper`. When you call `x`, you are actually calling `wrapper`.

Do not mark this answer as the answer. Mark one of the others as the answer. The point of this is to correct a misunderstanding so that you may then correctly understand one of the other answers.