# class decorator disables __init_subclass__

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, decorator, subclass

I have searched around for an answer to this question but couldn't find anything. My apologies if this was already asked before.

Of the 3-4 methods I know for enforcing from a parent class a given method on a child class (editing the `__new__` method of a metaclass, hooking into `builtins.__build_class__`, use of `__init_subclass__` or using `abc.abstractmethod`) I usually end up using the `__init_subclass__`, basically because of ease of use and, unlike `@abc.abstractmethod`, the constraint on the child class is checked upon child class definition and not class instantiation. Example:

```
class Par():
    def __init_subclass__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        must_have = 'foo'
        if must_have not in list(self.__dict__.keys()):
            raise AttributeError(f"Must have {must_have}")

    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Chi(Par):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

This example code will obviously throw an error, since `Chi` does not have a `foo` method. Nevertheless, I kind of just came across the fact that this constraint from the upstream class can be by-passed by using a simple class decorator:

```
def add_hello_world(Cls):
    class NewCls(object):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.instance = Cls(*args, **kwargs)

        def hello_world(self):
            print("hello world")

    return NewCls


@add_hello_world
class Par:
    def __init_subclass__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        must_have = "foo"
        if must_have not in list(self.__dict__.keys()):
            raise AttributeError(f"Must have {must_have}")

    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Chi(Par):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

c = Chi()
c.hello_world()
```

The above code runs without a problem. Now, disregarding the fact that the class I have decorated is `Par` (and, of course, if `Par` is library code I might not even have access to it as a user code developer), I cannot really explain this behavior. It is obvious to me that one could use a decorator to add a method or functionality to an existing class, but I had never seen an unrelated decorator (just prints `hello world`, doesn't even mess with class creation) disable a method already present in the class.

- Is this an intended Python behavior? Or is this some kind of bug? To be honest, in my understanding, this might present some security concerns.
- Does this happen only to the `__init_subclass__` data model? Or also to others?

Comment: The class you return from your decorator never defines the method you are talking about, why would you expect it to exist? You've replaced your class with an entirely different one.

Comment: I'd suggest reading [about how decorators work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5481739/364696); you have a fundamental misunderstanding that that post should resolve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember, decorator syntax is just function application:

```
class Par:
    def __init_subclass__(...):
         ...


Par = add_hello_world(Par)
```

The class *originally* bound to `Par` defined `__init_subclass__`; the *new* class defined inside `add_hello_world` does not, and that's the class that the post-decoration name `Par` refers to, and the class that you are subclassing.

---

Incidentally, you can still access the original class `Par` via `__init__`.

Calling the decorator explicitly:

```
class Par:
    def __init_subclass__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        must_have = "foo"
        if must_have not in list(self.__dict__.keys()):
            raise AttributeError(f"Must have {must_have}")

    def __init__(self):
        pass

Foo = Par  # Keep this for confirmation

Par = add_hello_world(Par)
```

we can confirm that the closure keeps a reference to the original class:

```
>>> Par.__init__.__closure__[0].cell_contents
<class '__main__.Par'>
>>> Par.__init__.__closure__[0].cell_contents is Par
False
>>> Par.__init__.__closure__[0].cell_contents is Foo
True
```

And if you *did* try to subclass it, you would get the expected error:

```
>>> class Bar(Par.__init__.__closure__[0].cell_contents):
...   pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "tmp.py", line 16, in __init_subclass__
    raise AttributeError(f"Must have {must_have}")
AttributeError: Must have foo
```

Comment: Also note: If you want the new class to be a subclass, you can just make it one. Change `class NewCls(object):` to `class NewCls(Cls):` and remove the definition of `__init__` (you don't need a `instance` attribute, because you'll be an instance of an actual subclass of `Cls`/`Par`, but the decorator's new class had better adhere to the rules `__init_subclass__` imposes). Normally, class decorators don't even do that, they'd have definitions of methods to add, then assign to `Cls`, e.g. `Cls.hello_world = hello_world`, then `return Cls`; they modify the class, rather than making a new one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I can clearly see it now even though I couldn't before :)