# Methods decorated with a decorator class do not have the "self" argument frozen

Tags: python, decorator

I have a decorator declared as a class:

```
class predicated(object):
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn
        self.fpred = lambda *args, **kwargs: True

    def predicate(self, predicate):
        self.fpred = predicate
        return self

    def validate(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.fpred(*args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.validate(*args, **kwargs):
            raise PredicateNotMatchedError("predicate was not matched")
        return self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
```

... and when I use it to wrap a method in a class, calling that method does not seem to set the instance of the object as the first argument. While this behavior is not exactly unexpected, how would I go about getting `self` to be frozen when the method becomes an instance method?

---

Simplified example:

```
class test_decorator(object):
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.fn(*args, **kwargs)

class Foo(object):
    @test_decorator
    def some_method(self):
        print(self)

Foo().some_method()
```

Expected instance of foo, instead get an error saying 0 arguments were passed.

Comment: +1 for "Simplified example" :)

Comment: I'd guess it does that because `some_method` is no longer a function, but instead an object - instance of the `test_decorator` class - so it doesn't create a bound method out of it. I have no idea how to make the scenario work with a "decorator class" though..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out - needed to define a `__get__` method in order to create a `MethodType` binding like so:

```
def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
    return MethodType(self, obj, objtype)
```

which creates a `MethodType` object when invoking the method on an object that freezes the `self` argument.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469956/python-decorator-self-is-mixed-up) post talks about the descriptor protocol