# Why do I get "missing required argument: self" when using a decorator written as a class with a method?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have written a decorator using a class. Below is the code

```
class to_uppercase:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, *kwargs).upper()
```

When I apply this decorator on a function, it works.

```
@to_uppercase
def format_string(string):
    return string
```

```
>>> format_string('wORD wORD')
'WORD WORD'
```

Now when I apply the same decorator on a method, I get an error.

```
class base_string:
    def __init__(self, base):
        self.base = base

    @to_uppercase
    def get_base_string(self):
        return self.base

s = base_string('word worD')
s.get_base_string()
```

> TypeError: get_base_string() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decorating class methods - how to pass the instance to the decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365701/decorating-class-methods-how-to-pass-the-instance-to-the-decorator)

Comment: A method is a function in a class. Did you mean "function" in your first example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a function instead of a class, but if you need a class, here what you can do.

## Add a `__get__` method in your class

When you use a class as decorator, get_base_string is now a instance of your class decorator:

```py
print(type(s.get_base_string))  # <class '__main__.to_uppercase'>
```

So, when the function is called, `self` is a ref to `to_uppercase`, and you don't have a ref to the `s` object.

Code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3296318/6251742

```py
    def __get__(self, obj, obj_type):
        """Support instance methods."""
        import functools
        return functools.partial(self.__call__, obj)
```

With this method, you interact with Python getting the decorator instance. Since you call it from another object, this object and his type is sent to the `__get__` method in `obj` parameter, and his type in `obj_type` parameter.

```py
s.get_base_string()
# def __get__(self, obj, obj_type)
# s go to obj, this is the self we need
# type(s) go to obj_type, we don't need that, consider renaming it "_"
# self is an instance of the decorator class
```

Without the `__get__` method, the called function is the `__call__` of decorator, where `self` refer to the decorator instance and no instance of the class from where we decorated the method is provided

So we need to return a callable where an instance of the class from where we decorated the method is provided as first positional argument, and that's what you do with `functools.partial` and the `obj` (our `self`, the instance we need). This partial will then be called.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the decorator for outside function is working fine
[image: decorator for normal function working fine]

Decorator for a class method is not working fine
[image: error for another class]

Using the descriptor protocol in the decorator will allow us to access the method decorated with the correct instance as self
[image: descriptor prptocol]
This runs fine

```
import functools
#decorater class
class to_uppercase:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, *kwargs).upper()
        
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        return functools.partial(self.__call__, obj)
        

#normal class
class base_string:
    def __init__(self, base):
        self.base = base

    @to_uppercase
    def get_base_string(self):
        return self.base

s = base_string('word worD')
print(s.get_base_string())
```

for more information or understanding please visit
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html

for more examples
[Python decorator, self is mixed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469956/python-decorator-self-is-mixed-up)

[Decorating class methods - how to pass the instance to the decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365701/decorating-class-methods-how-to-pass-the-instance-to-the-decorator?noredirect=1&lq=1)