# Possible to change a function's repr in python?

Tags: python, function, repr

I've only seen examples for setting the `__repr__` method in class definitions. Is it possible to change the `__repr__` for functions either in their definitions or after defining them?

I've attempted without success...

```
>>> def f():
    pass
>>> f
<function f at 0x1026730c8>
>>> f.__repr__ = lambda: '<New repr>'
>>> f
<function __main__.f>
```

Comment: While decorators are fun, it seems that the easier answer is to not make a function in the first place and instead make a class with `__repr__` and `__call__` methods directly, which can then be called as if it were a function.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, if you're willing to forgo the function actually being a function.

First, define a class for our new type:

```
import functools
class reprwrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, repr, func):
        self._repr = repr
        self._func = func
        functools.update_wrapper(self, func)
    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        return self._func(*args, **kw)
    def __repr__(self):
        return self._repr(self._func)
```

Add in a decorator function:

```
def withrepr(reprfun):
    def _wrap(func):
        return reprwrapper(reprfun, func)
    return _wrap
```

And now we can define the repr along with the function:

```
@withrepr(lambda x: "<Func: %s>" % x.__name__)
def mul42(y):
    return y*42
```

Now `repr(mul42)` produces `'<Func: mul42>'`

Comment: Please use `functools.wraps` for decorators to update the name and the docstring of decorated functions.

Comment: The problem is that `print mul42.__name__` would raise an AttributeError which is not expected for a function. So it would be: `return wraps(func)(reprwrapper(reprfun, func))` to fix this.

Comment: @ms4py In this case I think `update_wrapper` is slightly more appropriate/direct. I've modified the wrapper class so that it does this in its constructor. This way the update happens even if you use the class directly instead of using the `withrepr` decorator.

Answer (score 9):

No, because `repr(f)` is done as `type(f).__repr__(f)` instead.

Answer (score 5):

In order to do that, you'd need to change the `__repr__` function for the given class, which in this case is the built-in function class (`types.FunctionType`). Since in Python you cannot edit built-in classes, only subclass them, you cannot.

However, there are two approaches you could follow:

1. Wrap some functions as kwatford suggested
2. Create your own representation protocol with your own repr function. For example, you could define a `myrepr` function that looks for `__myrepr__` methods first, which you cannot add to the function class but you can add it to individual function objects as you suggest (as well as your custom classes and objects), then defaults to repr if `__myrepr__` is not found. A possible implementation for this would be:

   ```
   def myrepr(x):
     try:
       x.__myrepr__
     except AttributeError:
       return repr(x)
     else:
       return x.__myrepr__()
   ```

   Then you could define `__myrepr__` methods and use the `myrepr` function. Alternatively, you could also do `__builtins__.repr = myrepr` to make your function the default `repr` and keep using `repr`. This approach would end up doing exactly what you want, though editing `__builtins__` may not always be desirable.

Comment: The custom repr protocol is interesting, however it's a bit more complex, since you also need to consider nested objects inside lists, dictionaries or similar.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be difficult. Kwatford's approach only solves this problem partially since it does not work for functions in classes, becuase `self` would be treated like a positional argument, as explained in [Decorating Python class methods - how do I pass the instance to the decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365701/decorating-python-class-methods-how-do-i-pass-the-instance-to-the-decorator) - However, the solution for that question is not applicable to this case, unfortunately, as using `__get__()` and `functools.partial` would override the custom `__repr__()`.