# Return a custom value when a class method is accessed as an attribute, but still allow for it to perform a computation when called?

Tags: python, class, methods, descriptor

Specifically, I would want `MyClass.my_method` to be used for lookup of a value in the class dictionary, but `MyClass.my_method()` to be a method that accepts arguments and performs a computation to update an attribute in `MyClass` and then returns `MyClass` with all its attributes (including the updated one).

I am thinking that this might be doable with [Python's descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) (maybe overriding `__get__` or `__call__`), but I can't figure out how this would look. I understand that the behavior might be confusing, but I am interested if it is possible (and if there are any other major caveats).

I have seen that you can do something similar for classes and functions by overriding `__repr__`, but I can't find a similar way for a method within a class. My returned value will also not always be a string, which seems to prohibit the `__repr__`-based approaches mentioned in these two questions:

- [Possible to change a function's repr in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875442/possible-to-change-a-functions-repr-in-python)
- [How to create a custom string representation for a class object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932438/how-to-create-a-custom-string-representation-for-a-class-object)

Comment: `MyClass.my_method()` works by looking up `MyClass.my_method`, and then attempting to call that object.  So the result of `MyClass.my_method` *cannot* be a plain string, int, or other common data type, because none of those types are callable.

Comment: could you provide feedback on my answer? did it help you?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply (hectic week) and thank you for taking the time to reply to my question @GuilhermeCorrea !

I have added an answer with a minimal implementation of your suggestion and to better reflect that I am trying to update the value set on the method itself, rather than a separate modifiable param (but I will of course award the bounty to you). One thing I do not quite understand is why passing a list or dictionary returns an empty list/dict. I want to assign these data types as well, do you know how I can go about this (see my answer below for details).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Joel for the minimal implementation. I found that the remaining problem is the lack of initialization of the parent, since I did not find a generic way of initializing it, I need to check for attributes in the case of list/dict, and add the initialization values to the parent accordingly.

This addition to the code should make it work for lists/dicts:

```
def classFactory(parent, init_val, target):
    class modifierClass(parent):
        def __init__(self, init_val):
            super().__init__()
            dict_attr = getattr(parent, "update", None)
            list_attr = getattr(parent, "extend", None)
            if callable(dict_attr):  # parent is dict
                self.update(init_val)
            elif callable(list_attr):  # parent is list
                self.extend(init_val)
            self.target = target

        def __call__(self, *args):
            self.target.__init__(*args)

    return modifierClass(init_val)


class myClass:
    def __init__(self, init_val=''):
        self.method = classFactory(init_val.__class__, init_val, self)
```

Unfortunately, we need to add case by case, but this works as intended.

A slightly less verbose way to write the above is the following:

```py
def classFactory(parent, init_val, target):
    class modifierClass(parent):
        def __init__(self, init_val):
            if isinstance(init_val, list):
                self.extend(init_val)
            elif isinstance(init_val, dict):
                self.update(init_val)
            self.target = target

        def __call__(self, *args):
            self.target.__init__(*args)

    return modifierClass(init_val)


class myClass:
    def __init__(self, init_val=''):
        self.method = classFactory(init_val.__class__, init_val, self)
```

Comment: Thanks again! Is there are reason to check the `callable` as you do and to and to use `super().__init__()` or do you think the less verbose version that I added to your answer is equivalent? The seem to work the same for me.

Comment: yeah, its more succinct to manually check if it's an instance, and ```super().__init__``` is just to initialize the base class, in this case I believe all of those inherit from python's ```object```. I saw this being done in "Mastering object oriented Python" from Steve F. Lott, and I think it's a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

As jasonharper commented,

> `MyClass.my_method()` works by looking up `MyClass.my_method`, and then attempting to call that object. So the result of `MyClass.my_method` cannot be a plain string, int, or other common data type [...]

The trouble comes specifically from reusing the same name for this two properties, which is very confusing just as you said. So, don't do it.

But for the sole interest of it you could try to proxy the value of the property with an object that would return the original MyClass instance when called, use an actual setter to perform any computation you wanted, and also forward arbitrary attributes to the proxied value.

```py
class MyClass:

    _my_method = whatever

    @property
    def my_method(self):

        my_class = self

        class Proxy:
            def __init__(self, value):
                self.__proxied = value

            def __call__(self, value):
                my_class.my_method = value
                return my_class

            def __getattr__(self, name):
                return getattr(self.__proxied, name)

            def __str__(self):
                return str(self.__proxied)

            def __repr__(self):
                return repr(self.__proxied)

        return Proxy(self._my_method)

    @my_method.setter
    def my_method(self, value):
        # your computations
        self._my_method = value

a = MyClass()
b = a.my_method('do not do this at home')

a is b
# True
a.my_method.split(' ')
# ['do', 'not', 'do', 'this', 'at', 'home']
```

And today, duck typing will abuse you, forcing you to delegate all kinds of magic methods to the proxied value in the proxy class, until the poor codebase where you want to inject this is satisfied with how those values quack.

Comment: Thank you! I accepted the first answer that met my criteria, but this seems to work well too!

Answer (score 0):

This is a minimal implementation of Guillherme's answer that updates the method instead of a separate modifiable parameter:

```py
def classFactory(parent, init_val, target):
    class modifierClass(parent):
        def __init__(self, init_val):
            self.target = target

        def __call__(self, *args):
            self.target.__init__(*args)

    return modifierClass(init_val)


class myClass:
    def __init__(self, init_val=''):
        self.method = classFactory(init_val.__class__, init_val, self)
```

This and the original answer both work well for single values, but it seems like lists and dictionaries are returned as empty instead of with the expected values and I am not sure why so help is appreciated here:

[image]

Comment: I think this probably has to do with the star operator. I should also be working, but I'm very intrigued by this problem. I'll try to fix it

Comment: check my edited answer, I think now I put the last nail in the coffin.