# Using class as decorator for another class's method

Tags: python, class, methods, decorator

I have an issue with using a class to decorate another class' method. Code is as follows:

```
class decorator(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args):
        return self.func(*args)

class test(object):
    @decorator
    def func(self, x, y):
        print x, y

t = test()
t.func(1, 2)
```

It shows this error

```
TypeError: func() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given).
```

If called using:

```
t.func(t, 1, 2)
```

then it passes. But then if the decorator is taken away, then this line will have issue again.

Why this is happening and how to solve it?

**Edit:** second version of the code to show the self in `decorator.__call__` should be different than the self in `test.func`:

```
class decorator(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args):
        return self.func(*args)

class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 2
    @decorator
    def func(self):
        print self
        print self.x, self.y

t = test()
t.func()
```

This shows the same error. But

```
t.func(t)
```

works but not ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To work as a method, an object in a class needs to implement part of [the descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors). That is, it should have a `__get__` method that returns a callable object which has been "bound" to the instance the method was looked up on.

Here's one way that you could make that work, using a wrapper function:

```
class decorator(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        def wrapper(*args):
            return self.func(instance, *args) # note, self here is the descriptor object
        return wrapper
```

You could instead return an instance of some other class from `__get__`, rather than a function, and use the `__call__` method of that other class to implement the wrapper. If you're not using a closure though, you'd need to pass the `instance` to the wrapper class explicitly (as well as the function, since `self.func` won't work outside the descriptor class).

Comment: Thanks for the descriptor suggestion. I found a related question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365701/decorating-python-class-methods-how-do-i-pass-the-instance-to-the-decorator. As you suggest, either getting the descriptor working or using closure function works. This code is clear for the descriptor solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/45361673. I ended up using closure function for easier maintenance.