# Is there a way for a python function to know it is getting decorated at module load time?

Tags: python, python-decorators

as an example:

```
def decorator(func): 
    def nested(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return nested

@decorator
def decorated(): pass
```

is there a way for decorated to know it is getting decorated?

Comment: Why does the function need to know that it's being decorated? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It could detect some wrappers (specifically, function-style wrappers that use `functools.wraps()` by telltale attributes they add to the wrapped function, especially in Python 3). But a decorator doesn't need to add a wrapper, and if it does, the wrapper doesn't need to be a function, and if it is, it might not use `functools.wraps()`.

Comment: In short, I have run into an issue wherein I take a look at the functions argument list. When a I come a cross a valid function lets say, decorating said function can cause problems. I should clarify it is a use case for a library I am developing that I am worried about.

Comment: Then why don't you add error checking in the decorator? Why does the function have to know it's being decorated?

Comment: Because I am not developing the decorator. Already explained why it would need to know about being decorated, refer to the above comment.

Comment: If you're not developing the decorator, why do you care if it works or not? It's not your responsibility to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a decorator that uses `ast.NodeVistor` to traverse through the AST nodes of the function to look for decorators of the function. If the decorator list includes more than the decorator checker itself, you can then get the details of the other decorators from the decorator nodes:

```
import inspect
import ast
from textwrap import dedent

class CheckDecorators(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        if len(node.decorator_list) > 1:
            print("function '%s' is decorated by: %s" % (node.name, ', '.join(ast.dump(decorator) for decorator in node.decorator_list if not isinstance(decorator, ast.Name) or decorator.id != 'check_decorators')))

def check_decorators(func):
    CheckDecorators().visit(ast.parse(dedent(inspect.getsource(func))))
    return func
```

so that:

```
def decorator(func):
    def nested(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return nested

@decorator
@check_decorators
def decorated():
    pass
```

would output:

```
function 'decorated' is decorated by: Name(id='decorator', ctx=Load())
```

Comment: I believe this is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Following is a **partial solution** that works on closures that look exactly like your example.

```
import inspect

def decorator(func):
    def nested(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return nested

@decorator
def decorated(): pass

def not_decorated(): pass

print(inspect.getclosurevars(decorated).nonlocals)
print(inspect.getclosurevars(not_decorated).nonlocals)

# => {'func': <function decorated at 0x10e1408c8>}
# => {}
```

Decorated functions like yours will have closure variables, though there is no guarantee that others won't.

Also, there are other things in `inspect` that you can play with. Plus, it would be easy if `functools.wrap` is used in the first place (@kindall). For class method, you can look up [How to detect is decorator has been applied to method or function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19314405/how-to-detect-is-decorator-has-been-applied-to-method-or-function)