# How to restrict the acess to a few users in pyTelegramBotAPI?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm using telebot (https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI) to create a bot to send photos to its users. The point is I didn't see a way to restrict the access to this bot as I intend to share private images through this bot.

I read in this forum that through python-telegram-bot there is a way to limit the access from the sender's message ([How To Limit Access To A Telegram Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368557/how-to-limit-access-to-a-telegram-bot)), but I didn't know if via pyTelegramBotAPI it is possible.

Do you know how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late tot the party - perhaps for future post readers.  You can wrap the function to disallow access.

An example below:

```
from functools import wraps


def is_known_username(username):
    '''
    Returns a boolean if the username is known in the user-list.
    '''
    known_usernames = ['username1', 'username2']

    return username in known_usernames


def private_access():
    """
    Restrict access to the command to users allowed by the is_known_username function.
    """
    def deco_restrict(f):

        @wraps(f)
        def f_restrict(message, *args, **kwargs):
            username = message.from_user.username

            if is_known_username(username):
                return f(message, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                bot.reply_to(message, text='Who are you?  Keep on walking...')

        return f_restrict  # true decorator

    return deco_restrict
```

Then where you are handling commands you can restrict access to the command like this:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
@private_access()
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Hi and welcome")
```

Keep in mind, order matters.  First the message-handler and then your custom decorator - or it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably a hard coded check on the user id.

```
# The allowed user id 
my_user_id = '12345678'

# Handle command
@bot.message_handler(commands=['picture'])
def send_picture(message):

    # Get user id from message
    to_check_id = message.message_id

    if my_user_id = to_check_id:
        response_message = 'Pretty picture'
    else:
        response_message = 'Sorry, this is a private bot!'

    # Send response message
    bot.reply_to(message, response_message)
```