# How to limit access to a Telegram Bot in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I have the same issue from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368557/how-to-limit-access-to-a-telegram-bot/54088518), but instead using python I need to use JavaScript.

I searched all over here and didin't find any helpfull answer.

I need limit the access to my own id or username so only me can send message to it.

I'm learning programing and I'm not so advanced to "translate it" from python, so I would really appreciate an example of the code.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Filter messages by field update.message.from.id