# Limit the access of telegram bot through Chat ID

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have attached the code. I want chat_id to be accessed from the text file located at my local machine.

```
#constants.py
  chatid_list = []
  file1 = open(r'D:\\folder1\\chatids.txt', "r")
  for chat_id in file1:
       chatid_list.append(chat_id)

 #main.py
    def start(update, context):
   chat_id = update.message.chat_id
     first_name =update.message.chat.first_name
last_name = update.message.chat.last_name
username = update.message.chat.username
if chat_id in cp.chatid_list:
    print("chat_id : {} and firstname : {} lastname : {}  username {}". format(chat_id, first_name, last_name , username))
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Hi ' + first_name + '   Whats up?')
    update.message.reply_text( text=main_menu_message(),reply_markup=main_menu_keyboard())
else:
    print("WARNING: Unauthorized access denied for {}.".format(chat_id))
    update.message.reply_text('User disallowed.')
```

Comment: Hi. where exactly are you stuck? Please have a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as python-telegram-bots [ask-right](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Ask-Right) page

Comment: @CallMeStag - When Main.py file is executed. Output is always User disallowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that the elements of `chatid_list` are strings because you read them from a text file, but `chat_id` is an integer. So you'd either have to convert `chat_id` to a string or the elements of `chatid_list` to integers.

Answer (score 1):

As a cleaner alternative, you could consider using environment variables (e.g. with [dotenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546883/what-is-the-use-of-python-dotenv)) to add configuration elements like the chat IDs (as strings, as noted by @CallMeStag).

That would remove the necessity of having to format and read a file for that purpose. In this case, you can have a `.env` file in the same directory with:

```
#.env file
# allowed ids - users allowed to use bot
ALLOWED_IDS = 12345678, 24567896
```

I'm assuming you're using python 3 and can use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python).
So, you can throw your constants.py away and your main.py would look like below:

```
#main.py file
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

def start(update, context):
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    first_name = update.message.chat.first_name
    last_name = update.message.chat.last_name
    username = update.message.chat.username

if chat_id in os.getenv('ALLOWED_IDS'):
    print(f'chat_id : {chat_id } and firstname : {first_name } lastname : {last_name }  username {username }')
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id, f'Hi {first_name}, Whats up?')
    update.message.reply_text(text=main_menu_message(),reply_markup=main_menu_keyboard())

else:
    print(f'WARNING: Unauthorized access denied for {chat_id}.')
    update.message.reply_text('User disallowed.')
```

Finally, in case you want multiple functions to be "protected", you can use a wrapper as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54854668/3188654).

---

*Edit: added alternative local file types after OP's comment.*

You could also store your allowed users in a JSON (`ids.json`):

```
{
    "allowed_users": [
        {
            "name": "john wick",
            "id": 1234567
        },
        {
            "name": "rick wick",
            "id": 2345738
        }
    ]
}
```

And then read the allowed IDs as follows:

```
import json

with open(r'./ids.json', 'r') as in_file:
    allowed_users = json.load(in_file)['allowed_users']
allowed_ids = [user['id'] for user in allowed_users]
```

**OR**, you could simply drop all the IDs into a text file (`ids.txt`), with one ID per line:

```
1234567
2345738
```

And then read them as follows:

```
allowed_ids = []
with open(r'./ids.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    for row in in_file:
        allowed_ids.append(int(row.strip()))
```

Finally, replace `os.getenv('ALLOWED_IDS')` from the above code snippet with `allowed_ids`.

Comment: I have already implemented this method. I want to add 100 chat ids, I want the chat_id to be accessed from text file located at my laptop.

Comment: Ok, now I understood your env. Edited to show an implementation of what's proposed. Also added a JSON alternative, which allows some sort of user management / mapping with names instead of just IDs.